# Join don't return some rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to access field `IsAvailable` to use it in conditional statement.
This field is stored in the `Table5`

Query below returns 48 rows:

```
select *
from Table1 c
join Table2 cm      on c.candidateId = cm.candidateId
```

I changed it and added some joins, so now I can access field `IsAvailable` in `Table5`, but now it returns 23 rows and I need to get 48

```
select *
from Table1 c
join Table2 cm      on c.candidateId = cm.candidateId
join Table3 lpg     on c.positionId = lpg.positionId
join Table4 lpt     on lpg.linkPositionGradeId = lpt.linkPositionGradeId
join Table5 s       on lpt.linkPositionTeamId = s.linkPositionTeamId
```

How to get 48 rows?

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 2):

Use `left join`

```
select *
from Table1 c
join Table2 cm      on c.candidateId = cm.candidateId
left join Table3 lpg     on c.positionId = lpg.positionId
left join Table4 lpt     on lpg.linkPositionGradeId = lpt.linkPositionGradeId
left join Table5 s       on lpt.linkPositionTeamId = s.linkPositionTeamId
```